# Wordpress style stats for regular pages

Tags: wordpress, statistics

I am wondering if there is something similar to Wordpress stats or if I can use the Wordpress stats engine on a regular site (which does not use Wordpress). I really like the interface of the stats and although I have Google Analytics installed, I see myself more comfortable with the WordPress stats engine.

Can you suggest me a good solution. I would like a sort of real-time statistics generator of sorts.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "regular site", do you mean a site with static pages, or pages served from a different Content Management System?

The reason it's important to differentiate between static & dynamic is that dynamic web pages are built as-needed (or served from a cache), as WordPress is doing.  In this case, the CMS can hook a stats package into that event as the page is rendered, and the stats package can do its thing.

Static pages don't really have that same server-side processing, so you're sort of limited to the events thrown off by the web server itself, or JavaScript-based tracking like Google Analytics.  There are other JavaScript "engines" like that out there -- many of them linked to site promotion networks like Yahoo!'s MyBlogLog.

If you want to report off the server logs, you should be able to find a wide selection by googling "IIS stats package" or "apache stats package", or something similar.  This one popped right up on the top of both lists:

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - the wordpress.com stats plugin for wordpress.org sites: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/